# list subdomain of a domain using cpanel xml api php

Tags: php, cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi

I am using cpanel xml api.

```
https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php
```

i can create subdomains and delete them.

Now i want to list the subdomains.

Here is the Answer in API1 level

```
$listSubdomain = $xml->api1_query( $cp_un, 'SubDomain', 'listsubdomainsop');

$listSubdomainpaths = $xml->api1_query( $cp_un, 'SubDomain', 'cplistsubdomains');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$subdomainsList = $xml->api2_query($cpanelUser, 'SubDomain', 'listsubdomains');
```

If you want, it is possible to filter results using a PCRE regex:

```
$subdomainsList = $xml->api2_query($cpanelUser, 'SubDomain', 'listsubdomains', [
    'regex' => '\bMySubdomain\b'
]);
```